# Capturing data using JSON in HTML

Tags: html, ajax, json

I'm using AJAX to capture data in the JSON datatype format and then display that data to a webpage. Can anyone give me an example to follow?

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Can you show the partial code you've got, and what you're expecting the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your JavaScript (hopefully you're using jQuery):

```
$.get(yourUrl, function (data) {
    $(body).html(data);
}
```

The page will show the data that you received. From there you can edit the callback function to put the data where it should go.